# Download large file without buffering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I am getting an **`OutOfMemoryException`** attempting to download a large file from an MVC controller. I want to reduce demand on server memory, so how can I download a file without first buffering its entire contents?

My code is:

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = filename,
    Inline = false
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

var stream = new MemoryStream();
ExportService service = new ExportService(_mapper, Repository);
service.ExportVersion(view.ExportType, version, products, regions, 
                      indicators, periods, stream);
stream.Position = 0;
return File(stream, "text/plain");
```

I would like the content to be streamed to the browser as I am creating it. To try to acheive that, I passed `Response.OutputStream` to the service and wrote to that instead of to the `MemoryStream`. However, that creates the same `OutOfMemoryException`, since by default, ASP.NET buffers all content before sending it to the browser. Even if I set `Response.BufferOutput = false` (and return an `EmptyResult`) I still get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

```
Response.BufferOutput = false;
ExportService service = new ExportService(_mapper, Repository);
service.ExportVersion(view.ExportType, version, products, regions, 
                      indicators, periods, Response.OutputStream);
return new EmptyResult();
```

**Update**

I am confident that this problem *is* due to hitting the limit of available memory since the code works on one machine, but not on another. Furthermore, on the machine with the more restricted memory, the strack trace shows the error occurs at variable locations in the code, depending on the content being downloaded. Here is a sample stack trace which shows the exception occurring while allocating memory to a List object:

```
[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value) +62
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min) +43
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item) +51
    MyApp.Mapping.DocumentVersionEntityConverter.LoadMultiVariableData(DocumentVersion version, MultiVariableQuestionView view) in c:\svn\Client Applications\MyApp\Web\Config\Mapping\DocumentVersionEntityConverter.cs:207
    MyApp.Mapping.DocumentVersionEntityConverter.SetResponses(DocumentVersion version, List`1 questions, DataFilters filters) in c:\svn\Client Applications\MyApp\Web\Config\Mapping\DocumentVersionEntityConverter.cs:112
    MyApp.Mapping.DocumentVersionEntityConverter.ScanSection(DocumentVersion version, SectionView section, DataFilters filters) in c:\svn\Client Applications\MyApp\Web\Config\Mapping\DocumentVersionEntityConverter.cs:79
    MyApp.Mapping.DocumentVersionEntityConverter.Convert(ResolutionContext context) in c:\svn\Client Applications\MyApp\Web\Config\Mapping\DocumentVersionEntityConverter.cs:63   
    AutoMapper.DeferredInstantiatedConverter`2.Convert(ResolutionContext context) +57   
    AutoMapper.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ConvertUsing>b__14(ResolutionContext context) +10   
    AutoMapper.Mappers.CustomMapperStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +13   
    AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +130     
    AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +355
```

Comment: Maybe you should find out what piece of code has caused this exception.

Comment: It's happens as the `ExportVersion` method is building up the stream. If the size of the contents exceeds available memory, it throws the exception. It runs fine on one machine, but crashes on one where the available memory is more constrained.

Comment: "If the size of the contents exceeds available memory" what makes you say that? Look at the piece of code that causes the exception and find out why it happens! Post that code here.

Comment: I've already decided what the cause is; that creating a large MemoryStream is exceeding available memory, which it quite clearly is capable of doing. I am looking for a solution that addresses that problem.

Comment: You can't decide what the cause is, I don't understand that sentence.; The message indicates nothing about an out of memory situation. It appears you have not investigated the error and are unwilling to do so upon request. I don't know how you expect to solve the problem like that. I'm voting to close because the answer cannot be found like this.

Comment: I have investigated the error, and I don't think you have read the post properly. It starts with a statement about an OutOfMemory exception. I have investigated the error, and found that it occurs on one machine and not on others and at a different point in the code, depending on the content. I am unable to debug the app on the problem machine because it is a server hosted by a third party.

Comment: Right, if you write to a MS you get OOM. I get that. If you write to R.Output you don't get OOM. This shows that memory is no longer the problem. "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent" is a very specific error message that, I think obviously, points await from OOM.  Post the full exception ToString output (maybe taken from the yellow ASP.NET error page). Also, post the exact line that this exception happens at. Drill down, the `ExportVersion` line is *not* where the exception is raised! It is raised inside.

Comment: I have updated the post to give more information about the OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: The new exception is an OOM-ex, yes. But this is a different exception than "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent". Why is there a different error now? What did you change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82116/discussion-between-paul-taylor-and-usr).